# NoClassDeffFoundError when running java.exe from different directory than .class files

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn to run java apps from windows command line and I can't figure out one problem.

I have a simple class on my desktop:

```
public class Hello{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("1, two, three");
    }
}
```

If I run `javac` and `java` commands when I'm in my desktop directory in cmd everything is well, but if I go one directory back (so I won't be in the same directory as the .java and .class files) then my cmd directory is `C:\Users\Tomas` and my Hello.java and Hello.class files are in `C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop`. I can run the command `javac Desktop\Hello.java` and it works, but then if I try to do `java Desktop\Hello.java` I get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Desktop\Hello (wrong name: Hello)`.

I know that NoClassDefFoundError is throws when a class was available at compile time, but ClassLoader can't find it during run time ( found a good article about it [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)). 
I think the problem has something to do with the CLASSPATH variable, so I set it to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\ext";.;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin";"C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop"
```

(I included "C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop" just to try everything)
And I tried running the "java" command with -classpath and -cp options:

```
java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\ext";.;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin";"C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop" Desktop\Hello
```

And I keep getting the same exception. 
I't would be great if someone can explain my error and why this is happening, and maybe point even give some directions where can I read more about this.

Thank you.

Comment: When you exported it, did you make it a runnable jar?

Comment: I just wrote it with notepad and try to run it from command prompt

Comment: Tomas, Try and get an IDE. Eclipse.org has some. They help in the task of making Jars and coding syntax =) Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you :) I have an IDE ( in fact 4 of them ) I just wanted to try compiling and running classes from the command line, just to know how it's done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class

```
package Desktop;

public class Hello{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("1, two, three");
    }
}
```

compile (here `Desktop` means standart windows directory)

```
javac Desktop\Hello.java
```

execute (here `Desktop` means `package`. `Desktop/Hello` is fully class name)

```
 java Desktop/Hello
```

Comment: If you're a directory up from `Desktop`, then the `Hello.class` file will not be in the classpath when your run the java execute command. Or will it?

Comment: Sorry, but I keep getting the same exception

Comment: @Tomas `Desktop/Hello` means `Class Hello in package Desktop`

Comment: It works with a backslash, thank you. Why does it not work with \ ?

Comment: @Tomas `\\`` is separator in file path on Windows OS. So in first case (during compiling) `Desktop\Hello.java` is threated as `path to file`. `/` is separator in class name of your class.

Comment: @Tomas name of your class isn't `Hello`. Your class's name is `Desktop/Hello`. It's Java standart. E.g. full name of class `String` is `java/lang/String`

Answer (score 0):

```
java -classpath 'C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\Hello.class'
```

Should run it.

Answer (score 0):

Try java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\ext";.;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin";"C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop" Hello

I only removed Desktop from your class name.

Comment: Still the same exception